# Should I prefer passing the array or the function first as arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I came across the [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#filter) function in Lodash and I was surprised to see the array as the first argument while the function as the second argument.
Shouldn't be the opposite? Is there a reason behind it?

UPDATE:
The few programming languages I know are using the `filter()` method the opposite way passing the function as the first argument and the array as the second argument.
So I was just curious about the origin of this. Are there other languages or libraries that prefer passing the array/values first and the function after, even in functional programming operations like filtering (I'm not talking about callback functions).
One advantage of passing array/values as the last argument is that I can take easily advantage of [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
Considerations?
Thanks.

Comment: Why should it be the opposite?

Comment: @JJJ Thank you. Probably, I was misled by the filter function in languages like Haskel and Python where the array is always the last argument. Also, I was misled by the fact that functions as the last argument in JavaScript make me think they are a callback.

Comment: Probably because of functional programming languages, I see I big advantage using the function as first argument and arrays or values as following arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to using Lodash as a "functional" library ([Read more about Lodash FP here)](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) versus Lodash in its normal state. Functional languages, such as Haskell, follow the same methodology as the Lodash FP implementation. The benefits / cons are argued all over the internet, so I will leave that to other discussions.